# ViewHolder holding an android.widget.Switch, Switch not responding to listener

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview, android-switch

Ok, I have a holder, holding a bunch of elements that won't change except for the switch (obviously).

I reduced the code, for it to be simpler to read, I thought this would allow me to see in the logs the state being changed of the switches (which are generated dynamically from the adapter).

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.communicationfilter = (Switch)convertView.findViewById(R.id.communicationfilter);

    holder.communicationfilter.setChecked(!kid.isBlocked());
    holder.communicationfilter.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Switch State="+isChecked);
    }               
    });
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it, hope it helps someone having the same issue I had.

```
holder.communicationfilter.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "The switch is ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"switch checked for" + holder.nameTxtView);
        } else {    
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"The switch is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,"switch unchecked" + holder.nameTxtView);
        }

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the Checked changed method as

```
if(isChecked){
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Switch State="+isChecked);
}else{
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Switch State="+isChecked);
}
```

Hope it works ...